# Scrape Website Data Where HTML is loaded based on XML

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a webpage using JSoup library in JAVA. However, problem here is the data that I want to scrape is loaded based on XML, so when I try to parse that  from HTML it displays

```
<div id="report-details-container"> 
   <!-- Container where HTML template will be loaded based on XML --> 
</div>
```

instead of full HTML it just shows this comment.

How can I scrape that data because in inspect element I can see full HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I scrape that data because in inspect element I can see full HTML.

You can't scrape the original XML out of the HTML.  The XML is not in the HTML.

However:

- You might be able to reverse engineer the original XML ... provided that you know the rules for the transformation from XML to HTML (e.g. you have the XSLT file), AND the transformation is not lossy.
- If the transformation from XML to HTML is done using client side execution of (say) an XSLT, then you should be able to capture the XML *before* the transformation is applied.
- There might be a way to get the server to send XML instead of HTML.  That will depend on the server itself.

---

However, if all you have is an HTML comment like you have shown us, then you will first need to reverse engineer the process that loads the XML.  It is probably done with some client-side scripting.